# how to add active class to front-index in CloudCarousel?

Tags: jquery

I am using CloudCarousel for sliding image. I've taken code from this example http://www.professorcloud.com/mainsite/carousel-integration.htm . now, I need to add an active class to a front image. I tried to search for many days, but no help.

Could any one help me to do this?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Okay but how do we help you?

Comment: Do you know any options or methods to add class to front image ?

Comment: no????????????????????????

Comment: can we check which element is in front ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cloudcarousel sets highest `z-index` to the element thats in front on load and when `prev` or `next` button is clicked. so you could check for highest `z-index` from the set of images, and apply class to the `img` element that has highest `z-index`. For this, i guess you will have to customized the plugin itself, as there doesnot seem to be any helper function for doing that.